# Why is only part of the class attribute value used in this CSS rule?

Tags: html, css

*In html body tag:*

```
<div class="clock">
  <div class="clock-face">
    <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
    <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
    <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*In CSS file:*

```
.hand {
  <!--Some CSS Code-->
}
```

**Now i want to know that why full class value(hand hour-hand) is not used?**

Comment: `<div class="hand hour-hand"></div>` shows two classes, `hand` and `hour-hand`. You can select that div by `.hand`, `.hour-hand`, and `.hand.hour-hand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div element

```
<div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
```

has a `class` attribute that consist in a space-separated list of two strings: `hand` and `hour-hand`. The space is for separate them.

Using CSS selector you can select that div element by his class attribute value in these ways:

```
.hand {
  ...styling
}
```

or

```
.hour-hand {
  ...styling
}
```

In your example, by using `.hour-hand` you are selecting only the first item under `lock-face` because this class is present only there.
By using: `.hand` you are selecting the 3 div items that have class attribute `hand`.

My advice is to read more on CSS selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
<div class="clock">
  <div class="clock-face">
    <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
    <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
    <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are three hands, an hour-hand and minute hand and a second hand.

They are all hands so they probably shared some styling in common - maybe all the same width, same color and so on so it made sense to put all that common styling in one class which they've called hand.

However, each hand probably has its own characteristics too - maybe the hour hand is not as long (height) as the minute hand for example, so these individual characteristics will be set in other classes and there was probably some code like

```
.second-hand {
  ..some CSS settings...
}
```

The space between hand and second-hand shows that there are two different classes which must be applied to that element.